# Bootstrap Typeahead in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, sass

I'm using Bootstrap-sass and formtastic in my Rails application, and I'm not sure why the bootstrap-typeahead feature isn't working.

*Form partial:*

```
<%= f.input :tag, :input_html => { :'data-provide' => "typeahead", :'data-source' => '["hello", "hellow", "heaven", "helo", "herr"]' } %>
```

*application.js manifest:*

```
//= require bootstrap-typeahead //typeahead is correctly loaded, checked with firebug
```

*result HTML source code:*

```
<input :data-minLength="2" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="[&quot;hello&quot;, &quot;hellow&quot;, &quot;heaven&quot;, &quot;helo&quot;, &quot;herr&quot;]"
```

In the end, I will need to customize typeahead to get the performance I want, but even this simple  javascript isn't working for some reason. I cant find anything wrong with the code. Could anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**
I tried it in the javascript way as follows:

```
<script> //call typeahead
$(function() {
    $('input#type_ahead').typeahead({
        'source' : ["hello", "heaven", "heythere"]
    });
})
</script>

<%= f.input :tag_list, :input_html => { :id => "type_ahead" }, %> //input tag
```

And still it seems like typeahead fails to work. i.e) typing in "he" does not get me a dropdown of those three items in the above array. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Do you get errors? Does nothing happen at all? Does something unexpected happen?

Comment: @regulatethis, by not working, I meant when I type in a few letters, typeahead doesn't get triggered. In other words, if the source is an array of ['hello', 'hey', 'heyyyy'], typing in 'he' does not show the list of those three items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `html_safe` for:

```
{ :'data-source' => '["hello", "hellow", "heaven", "helo", "herr"]'.html_safe }
```

Comment: It fixes the array but typeahead feature isn't still working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the typeahead() method when your page loads? You need to do something like this;

```
$(function() {
  $('input').typeahead();
})
```

You'll need to assign a class or id to your input to bind the typeahead to it specifically (Rails probably has assigned an id to it automatically, I'm presuming you've omitted it specifically)

```
$(function() {
  $('input#my-tag-field-with-a-cool-typeahead').typeahead();
})
```

edit:

The following worked for me. It'll take a bit of modification to the rails part to fit your situation, but this definitely works.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('input#type_ahead').typeahead()
}
</script>

<%= text_field_tag :test_type, '', data: {provide: 'typeahead', source: "['hello','heythere','heaven']"} %>
```